# peewee multiplying integer fields by floats for linear expression - replaces numbers between 0 and 1 with 0

Tags: python, peewee

I am trying to add a linear inequality to a select statement in peewee,

```
r = r.where((tgt.attrs.NumberMissingOriginalIntrons <= 0.5 * tgt.attrs.NumberIntrons - 0.5))
```

Where `r` is an existing query being added to and `tgt.attrs` is a table.

However, when this is converted to SQL, it looks like this:

```
WHERE ("t1"."NumberMissingOriginalIntrons" <= ((? * "t1"."NumberIntrons") - ?)) [0, 0]
```

But the expression I actually want is:

```
WHERE ("t1"."NumberMissingOriginalIntrons" <= ((? * "t1"."NumberIntrons") - ?)) [0.5, 0.5]
```

Based on some testing, I have realized that this only fails if the values are between 0 and 1. Why is this? Does this have to do with the column definitions being `Integer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's related with your column field type (`Integer`).

Nevertheless, you can use the [cast](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=cast#cast) function:

```
from playhouse.shortcuts import cast

...
my_field = tgt.attrs.NumberMissingOriginalIntrons
r = r.where((cast(my_field, 'float') <= 0.5 * cast(my_field, 'float') - 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions(Currently, up to v3.15), this function is inside peewee itself and there is no need to import playhous.shortcuts .

Also, the function name been changed from **cast** to **Cast** a few years after [el.atomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831797/el-atomo) answered the question. (as mentioned in the [Cast](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=cast#Cast) documentation)

So for the code example above, we will have:

```
my_field = tgt.attrs.NumberMissingOriginalIntrons
r = r.where((cast(my_field, 'float') <= 0.5 * Cast(my_field, 'float') - 0.5))
```